# Is the "new" .isEmpty() pyspark function an action or transformation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The isEmpty() pyspark function (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.isEmpty.html) added in Spark 3.3.0 is an action?

I am asking this because, in the documentation page shared above, in the notes section:

> Unlike count(), this method does not trigger any computation.

I am using Spark 3.3.0 and when I tried df.isEmpty() to check if the dataframe is or not empty, the code still performed an action.

[image]

Am I missing something or there is a way to not do a transformation instead of an action to check if dataframe is empty?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The python api's are wrappers around the scala backend.  In this case [the function](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-3.5/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L654) is defined as:

```scala
def isEmpty: Boolean = withAction("isEmpty", select().queryExecution) { plan =>
    plan.executeTake(1).isEmpty
  }
```

which shows that it's an action and hints why it's faster (it attempts to process a single row).

In real terms it should be much faster than count() = 0 or similar checks, but definitely still incurs a cost.  Ymmv if it makes more sense to ask isEmpty before or after running a full action like write.