# How is possible to force Spark to use all executors instead of one when an action is triggered?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, optimization

When I coded a repartition using (Py)Spark 3.3.0 (in AWS Glue) like:

```
df_final = df.repartition(15)
if not df_final.isEmpty():
.
.
.
```

When isEmpty is triggered, in spark UI l, only one executor has showing "work" and the other seems to be IDLE.

Anyone have a hint to use all executors? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `isEmpty` intended to be optimized, so it will execute the minimum required to check if there is any data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know that but in my case works equal (in terms of execution time) to count(). The issue is that uses only one executor and the others 14 are idle

Comment: Your other question is pretty much the same in this case [Is the "new" .isEmpty() pyspark function an action or transformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78232933/is-the-new-isempty-pyspark-function-an-action-or-transformation). It has the same answer - it depends on your query

Comment: It's different Chris...your suggestion does not make sense...since the other question is a doubt between an action/transformation...this is how to force all executors to work